# Undefined function or variable "somevariable", matlab

Tags: matlab, undefined

Here is the error given by matlab

```
Undefined function or variable "stream".

Error in ==> proclpc at 158
stream = filter(1, [1 -preemp], stream)';

Error in ==> changepitchf1 at 43
[aCoeff,resid, pitch, G, parcor, stream ] = proclpc(input2, Fs, L);

Error in ==> voiceunvoiced14 at 126
      processedframe = changepitchf1(patch1, gci_2 , 0.7, Fs);
```

The same thing happens always, but sometimes it goes off when I initialize the variable. But sometimes it doesn't. I don't get the root cause of this issue.

`changepitchf1` is a function I created. I'm calling it from `voicedunvoiced14.m`. `proclpc` is a function used in `changepitchf1`. It is a function that comes with a toolbox for matlab.

Comment: try using some other variable name than "stream"

Comment: No.. tried that already.. doesnt seem to work ...

Comment: you are probably calling proclpc wrongly andmaking it break. Debug and check if your mistake is in the parameters of the function (wrong values).

Comment: post the code that causes the error. Are you initializing stream before that line?